# Split paragraph from docx file to sentences with python

Tags: python-3.x, split

I have a docx file that I read it with python using this code :

```
from docx import Document
document = Document('file.docx')
for para in document.paragraphs:
    print(para.text)
    text=str(para.text)
```

I try now to split the text into sentences ? For this I did like this :

```
sent_text1 = nltk.sent_tokenize(text) # this gives us a list of sentences
```

But i got an empty list as a result:

```
sent_text1
[]
```

Can you help me please to split the text into sentences?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be your answer
    import docx

```
filename = 'x.docx'

doc = docx.Document(filename)

paraGr = []             #ALL the text in the archive, separated by paragraphs

par = doc.paragraphs
for i in range(len(par)):
    paraGr.append(par[i].text)
```